# Magic numbers. Joomla K2. Wrong some categories links

Tags: categories

I have one category (Games) with subcategories (Gamesnames).

http://www.gamerno1.net/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&task=category&id=1&Itemid=113

The settings of all categories is the same. But, links certain subcategories return to the parent category (Games).
As soon as I change the alias name - everything works as it should.
Below is a list of subcategories and their aliases.

```
Ancients of Ooga    91810
Anomaly Warzone Earth   91200
Cloning Clyde   91800
Dead Island 91310
Demolition, Inc.    98600
Dungeon Defenders   65800
Dungeons of Dredmor 98800
E.Y.E: Divine Cybermancy    91700
Hard Reset  98400
Jamestown   94200
Post Apocalyptic Mayhem 91900
Ravaged 96300
Revenge of the Titans   93200
Rise of Immortals   90530
Sanctum 91600
SkyDrift    91100
SpaceChem   92800
Spiral Knights  99900
The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim 72850
Toy Soldiers    98300
Worms Ultimate Mayhem   70600
Xotic   92600
```

What is my problem?
Thank you!

Update.

If you create a category with an alias: 91810, 91200, 91800, etc. .. category will refer to the parent category.

Whyyyyy?

Magic numbers ...

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem.

I removed

```
urlencode($item->alias)
```

everywhere

and all earned the right.

Thanks for watching!!!